# yii2, turn existing unix values into an timestamp inside the query

Tags: yii2

Working on an exciting project which as columns with Unix timestamp instead of a timestamp, so I need to make these values readable timestamps, is there a way to do this inside the query itself?

```
     $query = (new \yii\db\Query())
     ->select(['a.created_at',
               'a.updated_at',
                ])
     ->from(['a' => 'product'])
     ->all();
```

// the idea

```
'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
     ->select([new \yii\db\Expression('from_unixtime(a.updated_at) as updatedAt,
                                       from_unixtime(a.created_at) as createdAt')])
     ->from(['a' => 'product'])
     ->all();
```

or you can use `FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s %x');` to create a desired format like `2015 13th November 10:08:01 2015`. see [**`HERE`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) for more details.

Comment: ok let me try it first on my machine will repost again @user759235

Comment: can you show theschema details for the fields how are you saving unix timestamp into thee table ? @user759235

Comment: As this project is not build by me I cant say, but for what I do know the column is an int(11), and when I use yii2 formatter it will return correct date/time.

Comment: ok can you copy any of the `timestamp` saved and the replace it with the timestamp in this query  `SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1255033470);` and try running it does it show you the date correctly? @user759235

Comment: i just verified it and it works correctly if i save the unix timestamp using `$model->created_at = new \yii\db\Expression ( 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP()' );`  and then retrieve it in readable form using `from_unixtime()` it prints the date correctly using above query, this is strange do you have the latest yii version ? @user759235

Comment: im using 2.0.12.

Comment: I now see that it is working, but im saving it to a .csv file which for some reason turns these values into ########

Comment: :D lol its because the cell width is less than the length of the date you never to about CSV otherwise i would have guessed @user759235